# Different sorting schemes in different sections of bibliography

Tags: biblatex, sorting, subdividing

**Update 5-Sep-2012:** Sorry for highjacking this question, but as the status of the accepted selected answer has changed (now multiple sorting is implemented with biber/biblatex), and I think it is a good idea to update the answer of this question rather than me posting a new but nearly identical question.

The question is how have different portions or fragments of the bibliography (separated e.g. by type) appear under different headings and each with a different sort order.

I've tried using the `sorting` option of `\printbibliography` as suggested by PLK's answer bellow, but the numbers come out in the wrong order. Minimal example follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{biblatextest.bib}
@BOOK{BookA03,
  author    = {Author Aaa},
  title     = {Some Title},
  publisher = {Some Publisher},
  year      = 2003
}
@BOOK{BookB02,
  author    = {Author Bbb},
  title     = {Some Title},
  publisher = {Some Publisher},
  year      = 2002
}
@ARTICLE{PaperC04,
  author  = {Author Ccc},
  title   = {Some Title},
  journal = {Some Journal},
  year    = 2004,
}
@ARTICLE{PaperD01,
  author  = {Author Ddd},
  title   = {Some Title},
  journal = {Some Journal},
  year    = 2001,
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[defernumbers=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatextest.bib}
\begin{document}

\textcite{PaperD01}
\textcite{PaperC04}
\textcite{BookB02}
\textcite{BookA03}

\printbibliography[title={Books},type=book,sorting=nty]
\printbibliography[title={Articles},type=article,sorting=ynt]
\end{document}
```

The order of the bibliography entries in the output is correct, but the numbers are not. I get: "Books [3] [2]" and "Articles [1] [4]", rather than "Books [1] [2]" and "Articles [3] [4]" as I would expect.

---

Using `biblatex` how would one sort different sections in the bibliography by different criteria e.g.

- **Section A of biblio**: `Sort by name, title, year`, and
- **Section B of biblio**: `Sort by year, name, title`.

For instance *Section A* would be a list of books and *Section B* a list of Proceedings where the Proceedings should be sorted by year.

**Comment:**

Different sections of a bibliography can be separately sorted by using sorttitle={}, see the example here:

```
@PROCEEDINGS{Feldman2000,  
title = {Feldman v Mexico, ICSID Case No. Arb(AF)/99/1 (NAFTA)},  
year = {6 December 2000},  
shorttitle = {Feldman v Mexico},  
sorttitle = {2000}  
}  

@PROCEEDINGS{JoyMining2004,  
  title = {Joy Mining Machinery Limited v. Arab Republic of Egypt, ICSID Case
    No. Arb/03/11},  
  year = {6 August 2004},  
  shorttitle = {Joy Mining v Egypt},  
  sorttitle = {2004}  
}
```

Is there another way to accomplish the same thing?

Comment: I how have a beta version of biblatex and biber which support a "sorting" option for \printbibliography and \printshorthands. Please contact me if you would like to try it.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This is not currently possible. However the functionality for this is implemented in biber already and will be made visible through biblatex in the near future. This will allow you to specify different sorting not only for each refsection but for multiple bibliography lists in the same refsection.

This is now possible with biblatex 3.x and biber 2.x:

```
\newrefcontext[sorting=nty]
\printbibliography[type=book]

\newrefcontext[sorting=ynt]
\printbibliography[type=proceedings]
```

In older versions (biblatex 2.x and biber 1.x):

```
\printbibliography[sorting=nty, type=book]

\printbibliography[sorting=ynt, type=proceedings]
```

Comment: It seems that this functionality is now available. Would you care to update your answer to provide an example on how to do this?

Comment: I have updated the answer to show how to do this with biblatex 2.0/biber 1.0

Comment: I'm having trouble getting your solution to work. I've updated the question to reflect this. Do you think you could provide me some help? Or should I better start a new question?

Comment: Did you try the `defernumbers` pacakge option?

Comment: Yes. The option *is* activated in my minimal example.

Comment: Ah sorry. One thing to check ... the manual says to run latex twice after biber whenusing derefnumbers ... can you verify this? If you run once, it will not work correctly.

Comment: Yes, for a moment I also thought that this was the problem, but I've checked and the problem persists even after running `pdflatex + biber + pdflatex + pdflatex`. Do you get the same result if you typeset on your own system?

Comment: @JuanA.Navarro The `labelnumbers` are assigned according to the document sorting scheme (here `none`; the cite order). Resetting the scheme in `\printbibliography` won't change the `labelnumber`.

Comment: @Audrey I understand. But then, is it actually possible to break a bibliography into sections with different citation orders? Or this remains non-implemented yet? I am also a bit confused then, as well, about the meaning of `defernumbers`.

Comment: @JuanA.Navarro Sorry - `defernumbers` as documented should have the `labelnumber` re-assigned at `\printbibliography`, but `biblatex` doesn't seem to properly handle the `sorting` option. Would you mind posting an [issue at github](http://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues)? It's probably a better place to get this resolved.

Comment: @Audrey, thanks for the pointer. I've just added a post there.

Answer (score 4):

Biblatex 3.0 (2015-04-20) introduces the concept of bibliography contexts for this. See section 3.6.11 of the manual. (For this reason the sorting option in `\printbibliography` has now been deprecated.)

Comment: And how to sort it now? For example, I want to sort citation in the text by year, but in the bibliography by names?