# biblatex: Single out specific bibliography entries

Tags: biblatex, subdividing

I'm writing a document and I want to split my bibliography into 3 or more sections, where the first sections single out specific entries in some specific order, and the last section shows all other entries which were cited in my paper and *do not* appear already in the previous sections. How can I do this with `biblatex`?

As a mockup, what I want to produce is something that looks like the following:

> ### Bibliography
>
> #### Very important papers
>
> [1] Some person, and some one else. The most important paper which
>   should appear at the beginning of the list.
>
> [2] Someone else. Another important paper which should appear second.
>
> #### Some other papers
>
> [3] Yet another person. A paper which is not so important, but also
>   deserves a special section.
>
> [4] The same person maybe. Another paper which I want as second in
>   this section.
>
> #### All other papers
>
> [5] Person A. Other cited papers go here.
>
> [6] Person B. Perhaps sorted by author name.
>
> [7] Person C. And these papers do not appear in the previous lists.

Comment: Does [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6967/how-to-split-bibliography-into-works-cited-and-works-not-cited/6977#6977) help?

Comment: It does.. it points to the right direction.. but it's still far from a complete answer to my question. Right now I'm reading biblatex manual to figure out all the details, but I'll be glad if someone else can give me a head start.

Comment: It gives you the "how to categorise the cited works" part. The question now is, how to sort those parts as you want them...

Comment: I think you're currently out of luck as regards the second part. (See the answer linked in my answer)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

OK. Here's an example (apologies for just ripping off part of my own bibliography, rather than coming up with witty fake bibliography items):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{biblatextest.bib}
@ARTICLE{walley00,
  author =   {Peter Walley},
  title =    {Towards a unified theory of imprecise probabilities},
  journal =  {International Journal of Approximate Reasoning},
  year =     2000,
  volume =   24,
  pages =    {125--148}
}

@ARTICLE{walley82,
  author =   {Peter Walley and Terence Fine},
  title =    {Towards a frequentist theory of upper and lower
                  probability},
  journal =  {The Annals of Statistics},
  year =     1982,
  volume =   10,
  pages =    {741--761}
}

@BOOK{walley91,
  title =    {Statistical Reasoning with Imprecise Probabilities},
  publisher =    {Chapman and Hall},
  year =     1991,
  author =   {Peter Walley},
  volume =   42,
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[defernumbers=true,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\bibliography{biblatextest}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{important}
\begin{document}

% Here you list important papers in the order you want them to appear in the
% "Important" section.
\addtocategory{important}{walley00}\nocite{walley00}
\addtocategory{important}{walley91}\nocite{walley91}
%Of course, walley91 is actually more important, but then you wouldn't see
% the effect of the sorting=none option...

\cite{walley82}

\printbibliography[title={Important},category=important]

\printbibliography[title={Further Works},notcategory=important]
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, [it's not possible to sort different parts of the bibliography differently, although it will be possible soon](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21564/different-sorting-schemes-in-different-sections-of-bibliography/21632#21632).

If you want another category, just `\DeclareBibliographyCategory` and then `\addtocategory` in the same way...

Comment: Excellent! It works nicely. It will be nice when we're able to sort different parts differently, but for the moment I think that I can happily live with this. Thanks!

Comment: @Juan you can cheat and just `\nocite` your way to a properly sorted bibliography. It might be tedious for a big document though...

Comment: The document is not very large, so I should be able to do it. Thanks :)

Comment: @Seamus, is it also possible to count the number of entries in each category? If I added manually via `\addtocategory` and `\cite` then I could increment a counter myself, but if I automatically create the categories and cite a random number of entries, I might want biblatex to count for me.

Comment: @FrederickNord I don't know, but that's a distinct enough question that I think you should ask it separately.

Answer (score 6):

the solution I use in this case is the multibib package.

http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.169.9738&rep=rep1&type=pdf

There you define multiple bibliographies, each with its own cite command and you can obtain exactly what you are looking for. E.g. with

`\usepackage{multibib}`

`\newcites{VIP}{Very important papers}`

`\newcites{OTHERS}{Some other papers}`

and then cite using commands

`\citeVIP{}` and `\citeOTHERS{}`

The bib commands are then renamed to

`\bibliographystyleVIP{plain}`

and

`\bibliographyVIP{VIPfile}`

and accordingly for `OTHERS`.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, but I'm specifically looking for a biblatex answer.