# biblatex refsections and appendix

Tags: biblatex, appendices

I am writing a document where I need to have a chapter containing references and a list of (own) publications. I use `biblatex` with backend `bibtex8` to do this. The list of publications is split into arcticles and conference proceedings. I used `\newrefsection` to achieve this. Two `bib` files are used: `References.bib` and `Publications.bib`.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
  \usepackage{biblatex}
    \addbibresource{References.bib}
    \addbibresource[label=own]{Publications.bib}
\begin{document}
  \input{Chapter1.tex} % main document with \cite commands
\appendix
  \input{Appendix1.tex} % appendices with \cite commands
\printbibliography % references
\chapter{Publications} % list of publications
\newrefsection[own]
  \nocite{Paper1,Paper2,Paper3}
  \printbibliography[type=article, heading=subbibliography, title={Journal Articles}]
\newrefsection[own]
  \nocite{ConfPaper1,ConfPaper2,ConfPaper3}
  \printbibliography[type=inproceedings, heading=subbibliography, title={Conference Papers}]
\end{document}
```

This works fine. However, I would like to have the list of publications before the references. When I change my code accordingly, i.e. I move the line

```
\printbibliography % references
```

to the bottom, directly before

```
\end{document}
```

only my conference papers appear in the References. This makes sense as I started a new `refsection` after the `\cite` commands in the main document and appendix. But how do I fix it?

Comment: You can use `\printbibliography[section=0]`. (Untested as you didn't provide a sensible test document).

Comment: There are also other ways to have your bibliography divided with biblatex, e.g. using `category` or `keyword`.

Comment: An example with `category` here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/21891/105447

Comment: There is also `\begin{refsection}...\end{refsection}` to close a refsection again.

Comment: @moewe Your solution also works, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can restrict your refsection by using

```
\begin{refsection}[own]
  \nocite{*}
  \printbibliography[type=article, heading=subbibliography, title={Journal Articles}]
  \printbibliography[type=inproceedings, heading=subbibliography, title={Conference Papers}]
\end{refsection}
```

instead of

```
\newrefsection[own]
  \nocite{Paper1,Paper2,Paper3}
  \printbibliography[type=article, heading=subbibliography, title={Journal Articles}]
\newrefsection[own]
  \nocite{ConfPaper1,ConfPaper2,ConfPaper3}
  \printbibliography[type=inproceedings, heading=subbibliography, title={Conference Papers}]
```