# biblatex: combine addtocategory and nocite into one command

Tags: biblatex

I am using the solution as posted in this answer:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/21891/8569
The important snippet is:

```
\addtocategory{important}{walley00}\nocite{walley00}
\addtocategory{important}{walley91}\nocite{walley91}
\printbibliography[title={Important},category=important]
```

Instead, I would prefer a new command like this:

```
\addtocategoryNoCi{important}{walley00,walley91}
\printbibliography[title={Important},category=important]
```

The effect should be the same. So, I guess I just need to define a new/custom command that accepts a comma separated list of bibtex keys as input, but I need some help with that...

Comment: Would you care to expand on what you are actually trying to achieve, instead of this particular technical problem? I do believe there may well be other ways to do it, if your scenario is similar to the question you linked to.

Comment: Oh, you are sorted already, I see!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since both `\addtocategory` and `\nocite` can accept comma-separated values, you can use

```
\newcommand*{\addtocategoryNoCi}[1]{\addtocategory{important}{#1}\nocite{#1}}
```

---

If you want to give the category as argument, you'll want

```
\newcommand*{\addtocategoryNoCi}[2]{\addtocategory{#1}{#2}\nocite{#2}}
```

---

If one of the two commands could not accept a list of comma-separated values, you could have went with

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\addtocategoryNoCi@i}[2]{\addtocategory{#1}{#2}\nocite{#2}}
\newcommand*{\addtocategoryNoCi}[1]{%
  \forcsvlist{\addtocategoryNoCi@i{#1}}}
\makeatother
```