# Multiple biblatex styles in one doc

Tags: biblatex

I'm working on a citation manual for university students. It will explain the use of seven citation styles (APA, Chicago, IEEE, Vancouver, etc.). Is there a way using biblatex to switch citation styles in one same document? (I read [this entry](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34827/biblatex-multiple-styles), but found it of little use.)
Cheers.

PS. And an out-of-topic question (don't know where else to ask it!) --- Does anyone know what does the "c" in Vancouver's date formats mean (e.g., c2012)? I don't think it means "circa", btw.

Comment: If you ride the development edge of biber+biblatex, this might (now) be possible.  See, e.g., [this link](http://tinyurl.com/6rk5tbs).

Comment: @jon The dev versions support multiple sorting schemes, but not multiple styles.

Comment: @Audrey -- oh, too bad.   @NVaughan: you may find the `pdfpages` package suited to your needs.  I also recommend [pdftk](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/); apparently it runs on 'Windows, Linux, Mac OS X, FreeBSD and Solaris', though I've only ever used in on Linux.

Comment: Thanks to all. I believe I'll have to use the `pdfpages` pages, as jon recommends. As to the second part of my question, any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding #1: use `pdfpages` (LaTeX solution), or [pdftk](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/), which is really a cool program.

Regarding #2: according to this site, the 'c' stands for copyright, not 'circa' (as [another site](http://www.lib.monash.edu.au/tutorials/citing/vancouver.html) suggests --- caveat lector!); it is used when the copyright date and date of publication differ by more than three years.  [Note: this answer has been edited to take account of the OP's better knowledge of the subject.]

Comment: Ok as to the first one. As to the second one, I believe it means "copyright" rather than "circa". See here: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK7271/box/A35550/?report=objectonly

Comment: @NVaughan -- Well, I did warn that the link was potentially suspect.  If you can confirm that your link as being correct, I'm happy to change my answer to reflect your input.  (I've never used the Vancouver style.  In fact, I hadn't even heard of it until I moved away from Vancouver, which is where I went did my undergraduate degree!)

Comment: Yeap, the link is fine. Cheers!