# Multiple bibliographies, multiple styles, discontiguous regions

Tags: biblatex

What I currently have:

- My master's thesis (modified book class) which consists of the following:

  - Chapter 1: a single file.
  - Chapter 2: five files, one section per file.
  - Chapter 3: a single file.
- A single bibliography for all three chapters in APA format.

What I now need:

- I need chapter two to have its own bibliography in a format which is not APA.
- I need chapters one and three to have *their* own bibliography in APA format.

I read the biblatex documentation on multiple bibliographies and I'm not sure how to pull this off.  The section argument to `\printbibliography` only takes a single value, so I'm not sure how to merge the two chapters.  And I have no idea how to use two different formats in the same document.

Please help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While it is no problem to produce separate bibliographies for each chapter using `refsection`s or `refsegment`s, there are two major obstacles for your needs.

---

To understand the first one recall that `refsection`s are kept completely separate and independent from each other. That means that you can cite the same work in two `refsection`s and it might get a different label in each (think numeric labels or the extradate disambiguation letter). `refsection`s are implemented in a way that makes it impossible to 'merge' two sections, you have already seen one symptom of this: the `section` argument only accepts one number. `refsegment`s on the other hand have no separation and independence of data, they basically only add an internal keyword to each entry that can be used for filtering by place of appearance later.

Your first problem is to find a sensible setup in terms of `refsection`s and `refsegment`s.

- Option 1 would be to use `refsegment`s for all chapters. It is then very easy to filter the `\printbibliography` by segment and even by multiple segments.

  In this option all entries will still be treated together for the purposes of sorting and disambiguation. This may or may not be desired (I think in this case it would not be desired).

  The fact that all entries basically live in the same environment makes it even more complicated to mix-and-match two styles than it already is (see below).
- Option 2 uses the fact that while it is not possible to merge `refsection`s or have real split `refsection`s, `refsection` 0 is special. All entries that are not within an explicit `refsection` belong to `refsection` 0, so 0 is the only 'splitable' `refsection`.

  Hence something like

  ```
  \begin{document}
  \chapter{Chapter One}               % default refsection 0
  Lorem\cite{sigfridsson,worman}

  \begin{refsection}                  % refsection 1
  \chapter{Chapter Two}
  Ipsum\cite{knuth:ct:a,sigfridsson}
  \printbibliography
  \end{refsection}                    % go back to 0

  \chapter{Chapter Three}
  Dolor\cite{sigfridsson,nussbaum}
  \end{document}
  ```

  might work. It does not scale since only `refsection` 0 is allowed to be split, but that might just be enough for you.

  A `refsection` approach would mean that the bibliography of chapter 1 is independent of that of the chapters 1 and 3.

---

Your second problem is that of having two different citations and bibliography styles in one document.

Officially there is no way to have different bibliography and citation styles (the basic situation in this regard has not really changed since [biblatex: multiple styles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34827/35864)). Depending on the specifics of each case it is sometimes possible to rustle up a short solution (see for example [Two bibliographies with two different styles in the same document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10104/35864), [Biblatex: Two bibliographies with different styles and sortings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/299064/35864), [biblatex: different bibstyles in the same document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/170358/35864)), but I'm having my doubts in this case. APA style is quite complicated and if your desired non-APA style is very different that could pose quite a problem.

Comment: That all said, while I can sometimes see the appeal in different bibliography and citations styles and split bibliographies, in this case the requirements seem to be a bit too arbitrary. Changing the citation style for a chapter just seems odd. And I still don't quite understand where the bibliography for chapter 1 and 3 should go? Is it one bibliography at the end?

Comment: `refsection` 0 is the perfect solution for merging Chapters 1 and 3.  I think that will actually work!  With regard to the apparently-arbitrary requirements, they are due to the fact that my department requires APA citation/reference style for its theses **except** when chapters are to be published as papers in other journals in which case those chapters are to use whatever style that journal uses and my PI had the unfortunate luck in choosing a journal which prefers a style which is distinctly different from APA.

Comment: Also, the bibliography for Chapter 2 will be within that chapter while the bibliography for Chapters 1 and 3 will be after Chapter 3.

Comment: @JackTwilley Ah, that is a very weird requirement and would certainly confuse me to no end if I were to read the thesis. Anyway for the split thingy `refsection` 0 does indeed seem to be a good match - the code snippet should do pretty much what you want if you add a `\printbibliography` at the end. Re the citation style: Since you keep things independent with `refsection`s, you do have a chance of getting a different style, but you will have to resort to hacks. I guess you would have to ask a new question with more details for more specific help with that.

Comment: I have accepted this answer because I have validated that it correctly addressed the multiple bibliographies with disjoint regions portion of the question.  As for the style, I think you are correct in that I will have to ask that as its own question.

Comment: @JackTwilley The style thing could get really messy, so you may want to think about creating chapter two in a different file and just inserting the PDF later with `pdfpages` or merging them with a different tool. You'd have to manually get the page numbering right between chapter 1 and 3 and you may lose links (I'm not sure if that is true), but it would be less trouble bibliography-wise.

Comment: You have described my worst-case scenario, and one for which I'm prepared.  The chapters use the `standalone` package, and I already have some Boolean variables that check for whether the document is being built as the whole thesis or just a chapter.  The custom title page just for the chapter works that way, and I think the bibliography style would be just as easy (_if_ this journal uses a sane style, something which I have not yet worried about), but you're right, I'd have to do some surgery either by-hand or automated.

Comment: With the MWE, can I have a subsection (e.g., `\subsection{Only a subsection, not a full chapter}`) instead of `\chapter{Chapter Two}`?

Comment: @hola I'm not quite sure I understand what you mean, but in the code snippet I showed for option 2 you can easily replace `\chapter` with `\subsection` and still get a separate `refsection` - in fact you don't need any sectioning command at all, the `refsection` is explicitly marked up with `\begin{refsection}...\end{refsection}`.