# biblatex - quote in chronological order but bibliography list must be alphabetical order

Tags: biblatex, citing, sorting

I want to use more than one type of specification in my bibliography. I want to quote in chronological order but have the bibliography list in alphabetical order.

If I am quoting 2-3 references in the middle of my thesis writing, I want them to be displayed in chronological order.

e.g.

---

{biblatex}

> The human race has had a fast and accelerating growth in terms of technology and communication, in the past decade, [Turner, 2001; Allis
>   et al., 2007].

{bibliography}

---

But When the bibliography is displayed at the end of the document, I want them to be displayed in alphabetical order

e.g.

---

BIBLIOGRAPHY

> 1. Allis, C. D., Jenuwein, T., Reinberg, D., and Caparros, M. L. (2007). Epigenetics. Cold Spring Harbor Press
> 2. Turner, B. M. (2001). Chromatin and Gene Regulation – Mechanisms in Epigenetics. 2nd Edition, BlackWell Science Ltd.

---

**How should this be achieved given than I use bib latex package? I have not pasted the code of my biblatex line, but I hope that some1 can help me sort this out as not many topics in this forum is handling it.**

Answer (score 14):

Having different sorting within the text and the bibliography is currently possible with the development versions of [biblatex](http://sourceforge.net/projects/biblatex/files/development/) and [biber](http://sourceforge.net/projects/biblatex-biber/files/biblatex-biber/development/).
(UPDATE: By now biblatey 2.x and corresponding biber are released and incuded in both MiKTeX and Texlive 2012.)

The sorting scheme for citations has to be defined in the preamble. The sorting scheme for the bibliography is defined as an option to `\printbibliography`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,sortcites,sorting=ynt]{biblatex}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet \parencite{cicero}.
At vero eos et accusam et justo \parencite{wassenberg,angenendt}.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet \parencite{wassenberg,cicero,angenendt}.
\printbibliography[sorting=nyt]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: With `sortcites=true`, *"citations are sorted according to the sorting order of the bibliography"* (`biblatex` manual). The OP wants a *different*  sorting order.

Comment: Your example doesn't produce chronological sorting for, e.g., `\cite{wassenberg,cicero,angenendt}`.

Comment: @matth The dev versions of biblatex and biber allow for multiple sorting schemes. Using `sortcites,sorting=ynt` at load-time and `sorting=nyt` in `\printbibliography` should get you most of the way there.

Comment: @lockstep Sorry, looks like I misunderstood _chronological_: I thought the OP wanted the authors in the order of citation, but of course it makes more sense to sort them in the order of publication. I will edit the MWE, but I don't have the dev version of biblatex available, so I can't test it.

Comment: @Audrey- do u know how to do that during load and run time? I searched but I can't find how to do different sorting techniques! would appreciate more helps

Comment: I tried how you mentioned here and it gives me error not allowing to recognize the sorting options when i use \printbibligraphy

Comment: @user15736 By now new versions of biblatex and biber hves been released, so all you have to do to get the example running is updating to the newest stable version.

Answer (score 3):

[matth's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60336/) was right for old versions of Biblatex (2.x). The MWE should be modified as follows to work properly with Biblatex 3.x versions:

Replace:

```
\printbibliography[sorting=nyt] % this option has been deprecated
```

by:

```
\newrefcontext[sorting=nty]

\printbibliography
```

Got the answer from:
[Different sorting schemes in different sections of bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21564/different-sorting-schemes-in-different-sections-of-bibliography)

Answer (score 2):

For those who are still searching the answer, here is how to do

```
\usepackage[
    style=authoryear,
    backend=biber,
    sortcites=ynt,
    sorting=nyt
    ]
{biblatex}
```

Comment: `sortcites` is a boolean option. You can't meaningfully pass a value such as `ynt` to it. I just checked and I do not get an error from `sortcites=ynt,` but it is certainly equivalent to `sortcites=true,` and does not set a separate sorting scheme.

Comment: I have to correct my earlier comment: `sortcites=ynt` is equivalent to `sortcites=false`. Only `sortcites=true` turns on sorting of citations, all other values will leave it turned off.

Answer (score 1):

I tried it in the following way and I succeeded:

In preamble:

```
\usepackage[
    style=authoryear,
    backend=biber,
    sortcites=true,
    sorting=ynt]{biblatex}
```

In document:

```
\begin{refcontext}[sorting=nyt]
\printbibliography
\end{refcontext}
```

I'm sorry I saw your question very late...