# Biblatex: Chronological sorting in citations only

Tags: biblatex, citing, sorting

Presently I am using `sort=nyt` scheme, which correctly sorts the bibliography section.  However, the citations are appearing as:

> (Author1 et al. 2002; Author2 et al. 1975; Author3 et al. 1999)

I would like for this to appear as:

> (Author2 et al. 1975; Author3 et al. 1999; Author1 et al. 2002)

In other words, I would like citations to be ordered in chronological fashion, but the bibliography to be ordered in `nyt` fashion.

My backend is bibtex and would prefer to keep it that way.  Biber has been giving me lots of errors which I don't have time to fix right now and everything else is working well with bibtex.

Edit:
I just found another thread with same question and tried the solution which involves assigning `sort=ynt` in the preamble and `\printbibliography[sorting=nyt]` at the bibliography level.  I don't get any errors, but the bibliography is sorted incorrectly now.

Comment: Sorting is done only via the backend and multiple sorting schemes are supported only by biber. What you're after is already addressed in the thread you mention (http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/60307).

Comment: Yes, I tried with biber, and I seem to get the results I want, but the compilation process is at least 3x slower with biber than with bibtex, and there is numerous error message which require hitting ENTER everytime.

I suppose I am between a rock and a hard place.  Why do journals play these shenanigans?  Makes you wonder what kind of people make these decisions, especially considering the fact that the publishing house uses LaTeX for final typesetting.

Comment: Biber is sorting entries two ways (not just one) and (likely) performing name disambiguation. Why should it be any surprise that it ends up being 3 times slower than BibTeX? The errors you mention probably go back to the encoding issues I mentioned to you earlier. Either change the encoding or remove those non-Ascii characters from your bib file.

Comment: @Audrey I don't think there are any non-Ascii characters in my bib file.  I explicitly use e.g. \'{e} for accents.  But is there a tool which could check for non-ascii chars in a text file?  It is a pretty large database, I would rather not do it by hand.  Also, my favorite text editor is 'vim'.  Thank you.