# Changing sorting order with natbib

Tags: natbib

I am writing my proposal and a professor asks me to change the multiple citation order in text, sorting by year, not alphabetically. Here is what I have now using the 'sort' option in `natbib` package:

one sentence (Blogs et al, 1995; Dent et al, 1994; Smith et al, 1992)

What the professor asked for is:

One sentence (Smith et al, 1992; Dent et al, 1994; Blogs et al, 1995)

Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 1):

OK, I did not find any effective way to do this in natbib. I just changed by hand, painful.
But I found that another good way to do this, using biblatex package.
Here is the link: [biblatex - quote in chronological order but bibliography list must be alphabetical order](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60307/biblatex-quote-in-chronological-order-but-bibliography-list-must-be-alphabetic)