# ordered citation in text with \autocite{} by date

Tags: biblatex, biber, sorting

I hadn't take care about citation order in my phd. I have used `\autocite{}` as well as `\textcite{}`. Now I would like to do this job automaticaly... and order by date. It's possible in a less tricky way than what @Audrey [proposed here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65809/sorting-citations-using-cites-command-in-biblatex) ?

a short exemple

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside=semi,openright]{scrbook}%recto-verso

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[babel=true]{csquotes} % csquotes va utiliser la langue définie dans babel
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{newunicodechar} %pour les caractères speciaux dans les biblio par exemple!
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage[
  maxcitenames=2,
  maxbibnames=99,
  style=authoryear-ibid,
  backend=biber,  
  sorting=nyt, %appel biblio par  name year name title ... on peut aussi fair ynt
  doi=true, 
  url=false, 
  eprint=false, 
  sortcites=true, %%pour trier ds le texte les citations
  %hyperref=true,
  firstinits=true,
  uniquename=init
]{biblatex}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00A0}{~} %permet d'accèpter les problèmes d'espaces insécable
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00A0}{ }

 \addbibresource{biblio.bib}

 \begin{document}
    babalbalbablalb \autocite{amblard_modelisation_2006, amo-salas_new_2011, anderson_applications_1999}.
 \end{document}
```

and my `.bib`

```
@book{amblard_modelisation_2006,
    title = {Modélisation et Simulation Multi-agents Applications pour les Sciences de l'Homme et de la Société},
    isbn = {2746213109},
    pagetotal = {446},
    publisher = {Hermes Science Publications},
    author = {Amblard, F. and Phan, D.},
    date = {2006-09-05}
}

@article{amo-salas_new_2011,
    title = {A new model for predicting the flight activity of Lobesia botrana (Lepidoptera: Tortricidae)},
    volume = {30},
    issn = {0261-2194},
    url = {http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0261219411002912},
    doi = {10.1016/j.cropro.2011.09.003},
    shorttitle = {A new model for predicting the flight activity of Lobesia botrana (Lepidoptera},
    pages = {1586--1593},
    number = {12},
    journaltitle = {Crop Protection},
    shortjournal = {Crop Protection},
    author = {Amo-Salas, Mariano and Ortega-López, Vanesa and Harman, Radoslav and Alonso-González, Agustín},
    urldate = {2014-10-28},
    date = {2011-12},


    keywords = {Logistic function, model, Ribera del Duero, Touzeau model},
    file = {ScienceDirect Full Text PDF:/home/delaye/.mozilla/firefox/xlpcg1ts.default/zotero/storage/RDS7EKN2/Amo-Salas et al. - 2011 - A new model for predicting the flight activity of .pdf:application/pdf;ScienceDirect Snapshot:/home/delaye/.mozilla/firefox/xlpcg1ts.default/zotero/storage/SRB26DAW/S0261219411002912.html:text/html}
}

@book{anderson_applications_1999,
    title = {Applications and misapplications of cognitive psychology to mathematics education},
    url = {http://act-r.psy.cmu.edu/papers/misapplied.html},
    publisher = {{ERIC} Clearinghouse},
    author = {Anderson, J. R. and Reder, L. M. and Simon, H. A.},
    urldate = {2013-10-16},
    date = {1999},
    file = {[HTML] à partir de cmu.edu:/home/delaye/.mozilla/firefox/xlpcg1ts.default/zotero/storage/JD7DJUB4/misapplied.html:text/html}
}
```

That give me 
[image]

and I would like 
[image]

Comment: So you want to order the citations by year-name-title?

Comment: Try passing `sorting=ydnt` as global option and modify your `\printbibliography` to use `nyt` sorting via `\printbibliography[sorting=nyt]`. This will only work up to version 2.9a of `biblatex`, in the as of now unreleased version of `biblatex` the sorting interface has had a major overhaul.

Comment: I whant to order the text citation by Year but \printbibliography by nyt

Comment: I realise that now. Does my suggestion above work?

Comment: no, in that way I can change the bibliography order but not the citation order.

Comment: So you tried `\usepackage[...,sorting=ydnt]{biblatex}` and it didn't give you the desired sorting in citations?

Comment: Formidable! I misted than in `\usepackage[...,sorting=ydnt]{biblatex}` I can specified the order and when I `\printbibliography[sorting=nyt]`  I can specified an other! Thank you !

Comment: Fine! Now that this is settled, I will vote to close as a duplicate of [biblatex - quote in chronological order but bibliography list must be alphabetical order](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/60307/35864). The only difference being that you want descending ordering in the citations and thus need `sorting=ydnt` instead of `sorting=ynt` as loading-time option.

Comment: :-S ok sorry for duplicate

Comment: Don't worry about it, it isn't always easy to find duplicates. After all, it took me longer find the duplicate than to write down what to do.